# What is the best way to import data having different types of nodes and relations between them?

Tags: database, performance, optimization, neo4j, query-optimization

I have a requirement in which I have to import around at least 8000 nodes and 19000 relations in total. There are different types of relations with different properties and the said is true for nodes as well.

The problem is time taken to execute the query. I have broken down the query in small different queries. I provide them different parameters and use `UNWIND` to process the data in batch in all sub queries. However, this is taking a lot of time. It takes around 7 seconds every time on my local machine.

Another approach I tested to reduce this time was to create a query consisting of `CREATE` and `OPTIONAL MATCH`es only. So, I would parse a BATCH and create a query like following:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (target1 { id: target1Id })
OPTIONAL MATCH (target2 { id: target2Id })
....
CREATE (n1:n1Label { ...n1Properties })
CREATE (n1)-[:r1 {...properties}]->(target1)
CREATE (n2:n2Label { ...n2Properties })
CREATE (n2)-[:r2 {...properties}]->(target7)
...
```

However, this was way slower, as it took database around 5 seconds to process each batch.

I am pretty clueless about how I can improve the performance. I have implemented creating indexes. However, there is not much effect they can produce.

Your input on this problem would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

---

UPDATE

This is how input json looks like

```
[
{
   p1: {
      x: "",
      y: "",
      z: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
      a: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
   },
   p2: {
      x1: "",
      x2: "",
   },
   p3: {
      x: "",
      y1: "",
      z: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
   },
   p4: {
      x1: "",
      y: "",
      a: [{...}, {...}, {...}]
   }
},
...
]
```

The properties are just dummy keys. I am not sure if I am allowed to reveal the keys so just doing it this way.

Comment: This seems like very slow performance for Neo4j. How are you connecting? Are you using LOAD CSV or some other method?

Comment: I am passing the array of data as a parameter ($data) Then unwind it and do other job.

Comment: how does your input data look like?

Comment: Updated in question